# Последний третий пункт

Tags: css

Всем привет!

Как мне покрасить текст в последнем третьем пункте в красный?
Т.е. если пунктов 7, то покрасить пункт 6, если 10 - то 9, если 3, то 3, если 8, то 6...

```html
<ol>
  <li>Пункт</li>
  <li>Пункт</li>
  <li>Пункт</li>
  <li>Пункт</li>
  <li>Пункт</li>
  <li>Пункт</li>
  <li>Пункт</li>
  <li>Пункт</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: А где такое может понадобится, например?

Comment: @VostokSisters, ну мой вопрос уж не хуже твоих :D Я делаю игру. Там выскакивает блоки и мне нужно, что бы последний третий блок был другим стилем. Знаю, что можно классом отдельным такое сделать, но хотелось узнать альтернативу

Comment: Ну я всё равно не могу придумать пример, где в игре это может понадобится... Мало я игр играл, что ли?)

Comment: @VostokSisters, видимо маловато :D

Comment: @VostokSisters, как доделаю - скину вам ссылку

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Для этого нужно использовать `nth-child` и `nth-last-child`.

В `nth-child` выбираем каждые 3 элемента. А в `nth-last-child` выбираем последние 3 элемента в списке.

```css
ol li:nth-child(3n+3):nth-last-child(-n+3) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Пункт</li>
  <li>Пункт</li>
  <li>Пункт</li>
  <li>Пункт</li>
  <li>Пункт</li>
  <li>Пункт</li>
  <li>Пункт</li>
  <li>Пункт</li>
</ol>

<ol>
  <li>Пункт</li>
  <li>Пункт</li>
  <li>Пункт</li>
  <li>Пункт</li>
  <li>Пункт</li>
  <li>Пункт</li>
  <li>Пункт</li>
  <li>Пункт</li>
  <li>Пункт</li>
  <li>Пункт</li>
</ol>

<ol>
  <li>Пункт</li>
  <li>Пункт</li>
  <li>Пункт</li>
</ol>
```

Это можно применять, и к последнему четвёртом, и к пятому... Просто нужно изменить тройки в *CSS* на нужное число.

Comment: Воооу... супер! Спасибо!

Comment: А не логичнее было бы сначала отбирать последние элементы, а затем делать выборку по четности? Странное мышление. И как придирка - скорее всего, такой селектор был бы быстрее в работе с более большим числом элементов.

Comment: Имею ввиду такой вариант: `li:nth-last-child(-n+3):nth-child(3n+3)`.

Comment: @VostokSisters, по скорости не знаю. Мне кажется, чтобы разница в скорости была заметна, нужно миллионы элементов так фильтрировать

Comment: @Yuri, отмазки пошли, смотрите.

Comment: @VostokSisters, а в чём разница? Что значит сначала и потом? Фильтры применяются независимо.

Comment: @VostokSisters, хотите - опубликуйте Ваш ответ, с блэкджеком и бенчмарками. А не стройте диванного эксперта в комментариях.

Comment: @Other, фильтры в css работают не на волшебной пыльце и не на зефирной тяге. Когда пишешь одинаковый в результате код в двух вариантах, даже на css, один из вариантов может работать быстрее. Нечем мне доказать это, бенчмарками по css не располагаю, а высказывание диванного экспертного мнения в комментариях не запрещено. Просто предполагаю и думаю, что лучше. А что, хочешь финтануть бенчмарком и доказать обратное?