# Последний четвёртый пункт

Tags: css

Недавно я увидел этот вопрос про создание отдельного стиля [для последнего третьего элемента](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/636089/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82).

Как можно сделать, что бы так выделялся каждый четвёртый пункт меню?

```html
<ol>
  <li>Пункт</li>
  <li>Пункт</li>
  <li>Пункт</li>
  <li>Пункт</li>
  <li>Пункт</li>
  <li>Пункт</li>
  <li>Пункт</li>
  <li>Пункт</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Вам самому не кажется этот вопрос полным дубликатом?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Всё делается таким же образом. Только все тройки меняете на четвёрки:

```css
ol li:nth-child(4n+4):nth-last-child(-n+4) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Пункт</li>
  <li>Пункт</li>
  <li>Пункт</li>
  <li>Пункт</li>
  <li>Пункт</li>
  <li>Пункт</li>
  <li>Пункт</li>
  <li>Пункт</li>
</ol>

<ol>
  <li>Пункт</li>
  <li>Пункт</li>
  <li>Пункт</li>
  <li>Пункт</li>
  <li>Пункт</li>
  <li>Пункт</li>
  <li>Пункт</li>
</ol>

<ol>
  <li>Пункт</li>
  <li>Пункт</li>
  <li>Пункт</li>
  <li>Пункт</li>
  <li>Пункт</li>
  <li>Пункт</li>
  <li>Пункт</li>
  <li>Пункт</li>
  <li>Пункт</li>
  <li>Пункт</li>
</ol>
```

Вообще это применимо ко всем числам

Comment: Зачем ответили, если дубликат?

Comment: Простите, сразу недопёр :(

Comment: Стоит добавить эту информацию в оригинальный ответ, а этот сжечь